# Core Data - getting values through a relationship

Tags: core-data, one-to-many

Let's say I have a table named "Coffee Mug" and a relationship to many types of "coffee".

I can access the Coffee Mug record and all of it's details, but when I try to get the types of coffee through the relationship I just get the pointer values.

I'm trying to create an array of coffee values like this:

```
self.coffeeTypeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[coffeeMug.coffee allObjects]];
NSLog(@"Filled Array with: %i records", [self.coffeeTypeArray count]);
NSLog(@"Array contents: %@", self.coffeeTypeArray);
```

My log shows that the array was populated with 5 objects. But instead of the strings that I am looking for I get something like this for each record:

```
"<CoffeeTypes: 0x7f460b0> (entity: Coffees; id: 0x7f46100 <x-coredata:///Coffees/t113639D7-6BA1-4FDB-9739-7781EE6460134> ; data: {\n    mug = \"0x7f40370 <x-coredata:///coffeeMugs/t113639D7-6BA1-4FDB-9739-7781EE6460132>\";\n    coffee = Columbian;\n})"
```

I know the answer has to be simple, but I have run out of search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the array are managed objects of the "Coffees" entity. The entity has an attribute `coffee` which seems to be what you are looking for.

The following should work to print the `coffee` attribute for all objects in the array:

```
for (CoffeeTypes *theCoffee in self.coffeeTypeArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", theCoffee.coffee);
}
```

*Note:* Perhaps you should reconsider the naming of you entities and relationships. Your "Coffees" entity represents (as I understand it) one type of coffee, so "Coffee" (without plural s) would be a better name. On the other hand, the one-to-many relationship from "CoffeeMugs" to "Coffees" is called "coffee". Here, "coffees" (with plural s) would be a better name for that relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that works nicely. I knew I was looking at the relationship instead of the value, but I just couldn't figure out how to get to the value itself. I agree about the relationship names, it would be much easier to understand that way.